# Combine two update queries into single case MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, syntax

I am trying to convert these two update queries into one single case query:

```
update product_varities pv
set pv.quantity = pv.quantity + iquantity
where pv.article_id = iarticleid
AND pv.size_category_id = isize;

update product_varities pv
set pv.status = (case when pv.quantity > 0 then 1 else 0 end)
WHERE pv.article_id = iarticleid and pv.size_category_id = isize;
```

This query works fine. What I have tried is:

```
update product_varities pv set pv.quantity = 
(CASE WHEN pv.quantity >=0 THEN pv.quantity = pv.quantity + iquantity END),
pv.status = 
(CASE WHEN pv.quantity > 0 THEN  1 else 0 END)
     where pv.article_id = iarticleid and pv.size_category_id = isize;
```

This returns

```
0 row(s) affected Rows Matched: 1 Changed 0
```

Can anyone help? thanks

Comment: Its just not updating anything

Comment: Your query is parsing `pv.quantity = pv.quantity + iquantity` as a boolean statement that would be returning 0 or 1.  I think it should be updating, unless the original quantity is a matching 0/1 by happenstance.

Comment: thanks again Gordon for clear explanation!@GordonLinoff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
update product_varities pv
set pv.quantity = pv.quantity + iquantity, 
    pv.status = case when pv.quantity > 0 then 1 else 0 end
where pv.article_id = iarticleid
    and pv.size_category_id = isize;
```

Apparently `mysql` allows you to update the value of the field to the result of an expression.  That appears to be what you are doing.

This way instead is updating the value of the field to a calculation `pv.quantity + iquantity`.

Comment: Can you explain what I was doing wrong as well please?

Comment: the query does execute, but as mentioned in the op it does not affect a row only matches the row.

Comment: @Harry -- this is what you're doing and for some crazy reason `mysql` allows it: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/68386e/1 -- basically you're updating the value to the result of an expression vs updating the value to the addition of the 2 variables.  This is the correct way: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/54464/1.